# Using Nim to Creating a vb6 dll that Returns String

Tags: vb6, nim-lang

Nim Compiler Version 1.6.6 [Windows: i386]
Compiled at 2022-05-05
Copyright (c) 2006-2021 by Andreas Rumpf
active boot switches: -d:release

Cmd Compile
`nim c --cpu:i386 -d:release --app:lib --nomain mydll.nim`

Hi there, I was able to return a Long value, now I'm trying to get string values.

I googled to find some exemples and find out here:
https://my.oschina.net/yuekcc/blog/775990

I'm getting this error:

[image]

VB6:

```
Private Declare Function MyStr Lib "mydll.dll" (ByVal s As String) As String
Private Declare Function return_multiply Lib "mydll.dll" Alias "return_multiply@8" (ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Click()
  MsgBox MyStr("?")  'error
  MsgBox return_multiply(5, 4) 'ok
End Sub
```

Another question, why the Alias has @8 at the end? `return_multiply@8`

Nim:

```
import encodings

const
    vbCodePage = "GB2312"
    vbTrue* = 1
    vbFalse* = 0

type
    VBString* = cstring
    VBBoolean* = int32

proc MyStr*(): cstring {.stdcall, exportc, dynlib.} =
  result = $"teste"

proc fromVBString*(a: VBString): string =
    return encodings.convert($a, "UTF-8", vbCodePage)

proc toVBString*(a: string): VBString =
    return VBString(encodings.convert(a, vbCodePage, "UTF-8"))

proc return_multiply*(a, b: int): int {.stdcall, exportc, dynlib.} =
    a * b
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to export `toVBString` in the dynamic library, you have to add the `exportc, dynlib` pragmas to it as to others:

```
proc toVBString*(a: string): VBString {.exportc, dynlib, stdcall.} =
    return VBString(encodings.convert(a, vbCodePage, "UTF-8"))
```

But the definition is wrong anyway - I don't know what type VB's `String` is, but it certainly is different from the Nim `string`, and I'm not sure why you are importing it in your VB program.

Also, I don't think it's correct to just convert the Nim string to `cstring` to pass it to VB - Nim's `cstring` doesn't actually "own" the string data, so when the Nim runtime frees the Nim string, the `cstring` of it will point to invalid data. I don't know if VB has specific APIs for that or not though.

Comment: Hi, you can ignore That type  `VBString`,  I just wanna get a string type.

Comment: I've tried `VBString(encodings.convert(a, vbCodePage, "UTF-8"))` and got the same error.

Comment: VB strings are a tricky subject. Internally, they're Unicode [BSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr), **but** when declaring a (standard) DLL prototype, when a parameter is specified as ```ByVal ... As String```, VB under the hood passes such strings as ANSI strings. See Jim Mack's post in [this old thread](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.basic.visual.misc/c/packZI_ayIk).

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Nim, but the way to create a VB string is to make an OLE BSTR. `SysAllocStringLen()` would probably be your best bet. Others in that family might be better depending on what your string data looks like and where it comes from. Check out the **[MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysallocstringlen)**.